# <select> dropdown a few pixels off

Tags: html, css

Consider [this Bootstrap bug report](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9649). Basically, the `<select>` dropdown is not aligned with the `<select>` element on Chrome and Safari (both tested only a Mac). @mdo thinks there there is no fix. I just want a second opinion.

Can the `<select>` dropdown be aligned with the base `<select>` element?

Comment: options always take the whole width of select box..actually the width depends on the largest element...i dont think you can change it's position

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: post a code sample of what you're talking about

Comment: Would making a custom css dropdown menu be an alternative? You could definitely fix whatever you need to that way. Just a little javascript I think would do it. That's the only "alternative" I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will NEVER style browser built-in tools the same across multiple browsers and across multiple OS.

I have been doing this a very long time and my best advise it to style as-best-as possible and reserve quirky css hacks for old IE browsers.

If you want to be super-anal about exact pixels, you need to not use the select html tag and instead use a ul tag.  Then use css to list-style: none;

```
<ul id="my_selectbox">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
</ul>
```

Then, style the menu to look exactly how you want it to look.

So think of this as a menu instead of a selectbox.

Then use javascript to make the menu drop down like a select tag.

(but that sure is a lot of work for a few pixels isn't it?)

Remember, you will NEVER EVER write a CSS file that makes all browsers look identical.  Just isn't how they are designed.  If you have a manager that demands it, they need to learn how this stuff works.

further note: you will have to also use javascript to store a selection.  I can write you a quick script that does this if you need it.  Not sure how proficient you are with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This additional style to the element may help:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```